# Excel: What's the best way to output a number based on it's place in a range?

Tags: excel, excel-2013

`A1` will fall within a range in my sample data.  What's the best way to search a range for `A1` to output the D cell number into `E1` please?

Example 1:

[image]

Example 2:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX(D:D,MATCH(A2,C:C,-1))
```

[image]